# php: ob_end_flush() stops header() from working

Tags: php, http, http-headers

I have read the other thread on this specific topic but I believe that there is white space being generated by `ob_end_flush()`.

1. In my code if I precede my call to `ob_end_flush()` with a `header()` the header works
2. If remove the leading `header()` and put it after the call to `ob_end_flush()` then the header fails to execute.
3. In the latter case, I inspect the page (Control-U in FireFox) and see one blank line

Here is the code with **BOTH** header calls.  again, the leading header works but if I remove the 1st header the header subsequent to `ob_end_flush()` fails.

```
header('location:administrative page.php');  //-- return

ob_end_flush();

header('location:administrative page.php');  //-- return
```

The problem cannot be related to any undetected leading or trailing white space above or below my "PROBLEM AREA" code since the 1st header works.

Any ideas?
======================================== addendum 2/12/2015
Thanks to both replies...
I need to pay more attention to my error logs in challenging times ...

The "surprise" to me is that evidently ob_end_flush() initiates a header send and thus "my" subsequent header construct is blocked. 
Line 101 is: ob_end_flush();
Line 105 is: header('location:administrative page.php');

```
20150212T083215: www.summersessiondevelopment.com/report.php
```

PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /hermes/waloraweb026/b1614/moo.aassdevelopmentcom/report.php:101) in /hermes/waloraweb026/b1614/moo.aassdevelopmentcom/report.php on line 105

so, my task is to now find the definitive way to flush my fputcsv() buffer before I close the file with fclose($fp) without using ob_end_flush();

I used a brute force method trying to find a way to flush the buffer so I will check to see if removing ob_end_flush() and only using:

```
ob_flush();
flush();
fclose($fp);
```

does the trick.

Again THANKS guys!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

[`ob_end_flush`](http://php.net/ob_end_flush) outputs the buffer.  You cannot have any output before a call to [`header`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).

If you need to store the results to display later, use [`ob_get_flush`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-flush.php) instead.

See the documentation and consider checking your PHP error logs.

Comment: John, thank you .... but I am a bit confused on what is considered "output".  the following line is executed "n" times before I get down to the flush constructs .....
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
..... the header conundrum with respect to ob_end_flush()  doesn't seem to mind the fputcav() "outputs".
I do) use flush() and fcose() but they don't always seem to properly spill the buffer.

below current code (the header fails) - but the only construct that always flushs the buffer.

ob_end_flush();
ob_flush();
flush();
fclose($fp);
header('location:administrative page.php');  //-- return

Comment: @GerryWilliams - I think you replied to the wrong comment.  As far as the `header` function is concerned, "output" is any text that will be sent to the browser.  Error messages, warnings, HTML, whitespace, anything.  If you have any of that before a `header` call, it will fail.